# Regarding a variable in C, is an assignation always equivalent to a definition of that variable?

Tags: c, compilation, declaration, identifier

Is there a difference between defining a variable in C and assigning a value to a variable in C?

I know that declaring a variable simply means telling the name and its type like `int a`.

On the other hand defining a variable means telling the compiler its value.

So in my understanding there are the following associations between these concepts:

1. Declaration - Name + Type   (of an identifier)
2. Declaration - Value         (of an identifier)

Comment: A declaration is merely telling the compiler that a variable with a given name has a given type, you can define a variable when declaring it or you can initialize it later. Although I am not sure of the use of the term "*definition*" in relation to variables according to the c standard, I am sure that the term "*initialization*" is used to denote something like `int a = 1`.

Comment: *On the other hand defining a variable means telling the compiler its value.* - No.

Comment: `int a;` is also a definition. Roughly speaking, storage will be allocated for `a`. `extern int a;` would be a declaration.

Comment: A declaration provides basic attributes of a symbol: its type and its name. A definition provides all of the details of that symbol--if it's a function, what it does; if it's a class, what fields and methods it has; if it's a variable, where that variable is stored.

Comment: The duplicate covers most of the question, but doesn't address _assignment_. For reference, the optional initializer is only valid with definitions (you can't write `extern int a = 42;`), but it doesn't change the type of the statement.

Comment: Sign.  As usual, the question got closed as a duplicate of a related question which doesn't really answer this one, and before I had a chance to post an answer to this one.  I can think of two big differences between definition+initializer, versus assignment: (1) Can initialize `const`-qualified array, but can't assign to it; (2) pointer initializations look difference wrt the `*`: `char *str = "hello";`, but `str = "hello".

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for the information. I believe that it's a little bit sad how eager are people here to close questions as soon as possible as if closing a question is some kind of badge of honor.

Comment: @SteveSummit Detail: `int a;` as an object with file scope, is a _tentative definition_. §6.9.2.  Storage may not be allocated, depends on the rest of the file's code.  Unfortunately not covered in the dupe.

Comment: @SteveSummit Concerning [before I had a chance to post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546058/regarding-a-variable-in-c-is-an-assignation-always-equivalent-to-a-definition-o#comment80047027_46546058), vote to [re-open](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) - as you have that privilege.